# adding conditions inside a for loop

Tags: java

I am doing some codingbat challenges for java. In one challenge, you are to return true if the given array in its first 2 or last 2 elements have a 1 followed by a 3.

**Example:**

```
unlucky1([1, 3, 4, 5]) → true
unlucky1([2, 1, 3, 4, 5]) → true
unlucky1([1, 1, 1]) → false
```

As such, I have the following:

```
for(int i=0, j=nums.length-1; i<nums.length-1; i++, j--) {
   if((i<3&&nums[i]==1&&nums[i+1]==3)) {
      return true;
   }
   else if(j>3&&nums[j]==3&&nums[j-1]==1) {
      return true;
   }
}
  return false;
```

My question is, is there a better way to set the conditions? I do not like the idea of checking if the iterating variables are less than / greater than a constant. My code passes for all of their tests but one, however I feel that it is flawed/messy. How can I efficiently check if the last two & first two indexes have a 1 followed by a 3 without checking if `j>3` or `i<3`?

The test that it does not pass is with the following array: `[1, 1, 1, 3, 1]` My code returns true when the test is supposedly false.

Comment: What's the correct result for your failed test? It wasn't clear to me from the problem description.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for pointing that out. Mine returns true but it should be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use any loops, edited as per shmosels comment

```
if (arr[0] == 1 && arr[1] == 3 ||
    arr[1] == 1 && arr[2] == 3 ||
    arr [arr.length -2]  == 1 && arr[arr.length - 1] == 3)
    return true;
```

Comment: `|| arr[1] = 1 && arr[2] == 3`

Comment: @shmosel `arr[1] = 1` eek, I hope not.  Seriously thanks for the comment